# Launching Data Usage Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to check at my app's startup whether there is Internet connection or not.
I prompt to the user this dialog in case there was no internet access:

[image: No internet connection]

Once the user taps on "Open mobile network's settings", I want
 to launch the "Data usage" activity:

[image: Data usage activity]

I used 
`Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);`
But it leads me to this activity:

[image: Network settings]

any ideas or work-arounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
```

leads to this activity:

[image]

does the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
startActivity(intent);
```